# Java JDBC thows com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException for \'Test1\' value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have below table:
dummy_tbl

```
  |id |Name |
  ----------
  |1  |Test1|
  |2  |Test2|
```

When I try to execute below query in SQlyog - MySql(5.6.80) it's working fine:

```
 select * from dummy_tbl where name like \'Test1\';
```

But same query when I tried from code using JDBC statement it's throwing below error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Test1\'' at line 1
```

Code snipped from code:

```
  String sql = "SELECT * from dummy_tbl where name like \'Test1\'"; 
  Statement stmt= conn.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements. That will prevent sql injection and escape special character

Comment: We would need to see your Java code, but in any case you should use prepared statements which would allow you to totally avoid this current error.

Comment: Remove the backslash in front of the single quotes and add %sign after Test

Comment: @Jen, I know PreparedStatement used to prevent sql injection but this is requirement for my lagacy code.

Comment: @Jens, I know if I remove backslash than it will work but if this query with backslash working in MySql than it shold also work in java code.

Comment: It would not work in mysql. Because backslash is java escape character

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Let say below is my code:                                         
          String sql = "SELECT * from dummy_tbl where name like \'Test\'"; Statement stmt= conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: @Jens it's working fine in SQLYog with MySql (5.6.80) server.

Comment: Any requirement not to use `PreparedStatements` should be reported to your security team for overturning.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining legacy code that would effectively prevent using `PreparedStatements`.

Comment: @Kayaman I have code which has complex query with Statement, now we have used custom sanitation to sanitize input parameter instead of rewriting the query with PreparedStatement.

Comment: @EJP it's not requirement but because of complex existing query instead of rewriting query for PraparedStatement we have use custom sanitation process to sanitize input parameter.

Comment: I don't really see what the big issue is with using `PreparedStatement`. All you need to do is set placeholders and then you can get rid of your horrible manual sanitation code. There's no downside if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the statement should have been

```
select * from dummy_tbl where name like 'Test%'
```

but it was "sanitized" adding backslashes.

In that case use a `PreparedStatement` - which anyway is the correct manner (escaping itself, against SQL injection):

```
String sql = "select * from dummy_tbl where name like ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "Test%");
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already know PreparedStatement is correct way to prevent Sql Injection. but in my case I have no control on input value because of some custom sanitation performed on input.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query to:
`select * from dummy_tbl where name like 'Test%';`

should fix your issue.

Comment: I know that above will work, here I have no any control to edit that existing sanitizing method which add \ to single quote. And if the smae query work in Sqlyog than it should also work in java code.

Comment: @Kanti though Saheed is right, and I stole his solution above. That Sqlyog accepts a backslash there is probably due to some hacking in the SQL parsing.

Answer (score -3):

try this once

select * from dummy_tbl where name like \\'Test\\';